# Polynomial with coefficients 1.

Tags: polynomials

How can I solve (only for real solutions) an equation of the form $c = x + x^2 + ... + x^n$, where $c \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ are constants.

My first instinct was to rewrite this as:

$c = x(1 + x(1 + ... (x)))$

But I'm not sure if that's of any use.

Thanks :)

Comment: In general, you will need numerical methods. There is no general formula for the roots of polynomials with degree $5$ or more. An explicite example that cannot be solved by radicals is $x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x-7=0$ since the galois group of the polynomial over $\mathbb Q$ is $S_6$

Comment: Is it for $c>0$ ? Large values ?

Comment: Oh sorry, @ClaudeLeibovici. I should have specified that: $c \in \mathbb{N}$ and generally it will be less than $1000$.

Answer (score 2):

$x^n+\ldots+x+1 = \frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$ and so

$c = x^n+\ldots+x = \frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1} - 1$ or

$x^{n+1}-1 = (c+1)(x-1)$, i.e.,

$x^{n+1} - (c+1)x + c = 0$.

Comment: Nice simplification (+1). Nevertheless, numerical methods will be inevitable in general.

Comment: We have to be careful , if $x=1$ : the right side is then $n$. Hence $x=1$ is only a solution, if $c=n$. But the equation in the answer is always satisfied by $x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

@Wuestenfux gave the most convenient form for the problem.

Assuming $c>0$, consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=x^{n+1} - (c+1)x + c $$ for which
$$f'(x)=(n+1)x^n- (c+1)\qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(x)=n(n+1)x $$ The first derivative cancels at
$$x_*= \Bigg[\frac {c+1}{n+1}\Bigg]^{\frac 1n}$$ To get an *estimate* of  the solution, expand $f(x)$ as Taylor series around $x=x_*$. This will give
$$f(x)=f(x_*)+\frac 12 f''(x_*) (x-x_*)^2+O\left((x-x_*)^3\right)$$ This will give
$$x_0=x_*+\sqrt{-2 \frac{f(x_*)}{f''(x_*)}}$$ from which you can start Newton iterations
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$

Since you wrote in comments that, usually $c<10^3$, let me be generous using $c=10^4$. I report in the table the value of the $x_0$, $x_1$ and the "exact" solution.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
n & x_0 & x_1 & \text{solution} \\
 5 & 6.58133 & 6.18432 &  6.08727 \\
 10 & 2.53756 & 2.42381 &  2.37859 \\
 15 & 1.83624 & 1.77471 &  1.74604 \\
 20 & 1.56196 & 1.52078 &  1.50023 \\
 25 & 1.41831 & 1.38771 &  1.37193 \\
 30 & 1.33069 & 1.30652 &  1.29384 \\
 35 & 1.27200 & 1.25210 &  1.24160 \\
 40 & 1.23008 & 1.21323 &  1.20433 \\
 45 & 1.19874 & 1.18417 &  1.17649 \\
 50 & 1.17448 & 1.16166 &  1.15494
\end{array}
\right)$$ You can conceive that, with such an $x_0$, Newton method or, better, Halley or househloder methods will converge within very few iterations.